# Good plot same as my data range?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a data frame data, I would like draw a proper density plot for it.When I have drown plot the interval is shown a wider range than my data.

input:

```
          X                 Y
1  0.4078791          0.471845
2  0.2892282          0.205871
3  0.4254774          0.407548
4  0.4749196          0.396765
5  0.2763627          0.142572
6  0.3942402          0.457668
7  0.2427948          0.248003
8  0.3117754          0.322484
9  0.4350599          0.450679
10 0.4459200          0.338858
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how a kernel density estimation works. The result must cover a wider range than your data. You can try different kernels and bandwidth algorithms or fiddle with the `adjust` parameter, but you actually want the density estimate to cover a wider range than your data. Otherwise it wouldn't be a *proper* density estimate.